# AsyncTask fires error message while trying to get tokens

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-play-services, proximityapi

Im trying to get the tokens in background for authenticating myself with google playservices but Im unable to do so.

My code to get token is as follows,

```
private class GetTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return fetchToken(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                ProximityApi.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                        .setAuthToken(result);
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

The error response that I get is as follows,

```
10-06 03:05:08.855    1876-1893/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 21.270ms
10-06 03:05:11.402    1876-1893/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 65.002ms
10-06 03:05:11.463    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: DeviceManagementSyncDisabled
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.zza(Unknown Source)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon.MainActivity.fetchToken(MainActivity.java:106)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:24)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon.MainActivity$GetTokenTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:87)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon.MainActivity$GetTokenTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:82)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-06 03:05:11.634    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-06 03:05:11.635    1876-2140/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.google.android.gms time:6855445
10-06 03:05:11.722    1876-1876/com.infotech.palmtree.proxybeacon I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.google.android.gms time:6855532
```

Comment: post full logcat result

Comment: Is it for fetching the Token for GCM. Because you are missing something that is not rightly achieved . May be something that needs to be in Worker thread

Comment: I have posted the full logcat result

Comment: Not GCM but I'm using Proximity beacons API

Comment: i hope there is an internet permission defined in manifest.xml

Comment: yes permission for internet has been defined in manifest.xml but still I'm getting that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. This: `UserRecoverableAuthException: DeviceManagementSyncDisabled` seems to be the root cause. ([Explanation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/UserRecoverableAuthException?hl=en) of the said error)

I would assume you need to enable sync on your testing device and that should resolve the error.

PS: the following text in logs is because the Auth failed.